# GWT Compilation Failed in new GWT 7 from existing Old project

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

Hi I have updated my Eclipse Kepler to Oxygen, and GWT 2.6.1 to GWT 2.7 and java 7 to java 8 using this [link](https://developers.google.com/eclipse/).

Then I created one sample project which runs successfully.

When I added my existing project into new Eclipse Oxygen then I get the following error:

`Super Dev Mode starting up
   Finding entry point classes
      Tracing compile failure path for type 
    'com.slicktechnologies.client.Slick_Erp'
         [ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay/2017/FROM%20OXGEN%20ECLIPSE%2010%20AUGUST%202017%20ONWORDS/10%20august%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/slicktechnologies/client/Slick_Erp.java'`

Any help would be appreciated.

As i Compiled with Log debug then error is :-

```
 `Loading inherited module 'com.slicktechnologies.Slick_Erp'
   Module location: file:/C:/Vijay/2017/FROM%20OXGEN%20ECLIPSE%2010%20AUGUST%202017%20ONWORDS/10%20august%202017/Slick%20Erp/src/com/slicktechnologies/Slick_Erp.gwt.xml
Checking for updates
   Failed to obtain current version info via HTTP
   Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.Core'
      Module location: jar:file:/C:/Vijay/2017/NEW%20ECLIPSE%20Settings/eclipse/plugins/com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt27_2.7.0.201707251900/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/Core.gwt.xml
      Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.dev.jjs.intrinsic.Intrinsic'
         Module location: jar:file:/C:/Vijay/2017/NEW%20ECLIPSE%20Settings/eclipse/plugins/com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt27_2.7.0.201707251900/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-dev.jar!/com/google/gwt/dev/jjs/intrinsic/Intrinsic.gwt.xml
         Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.lang.LongLib'
            Module location: jar:file:/C:/Vijay/2017/NEW%20ECLIPSE%20Settings/eclipse/plugins/com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt27_2.7.0.201707251900/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-dev.jar!/com/google/gwt/lang/LongLib.gwt.xml
      Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.core.CompilerParameters'
         Module location: jar:file:/C:/Vijay/2017/NEW%20ECLIPSE%20Settings/eclipse/plugins/com.gwtplugins.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle.gwt27_2.7.0.201707251900/gwt-2.7.0/gwt-user.jar!/com/google/gwt/core/CompilerParameters.gwt.xml
  `
```

Comment: Aren't there any more details about the error? If there aren't, try running dev mode with logLevel set to debug; current info is insufficient for anyone to help you.

Comment: @Andrei Thank u for your valuable response i compiled with debug then the error is updated please check

Comment: I'm interested in whatever it is shown *after* the line `[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay...`. That's usually the place where the errors are.
Your edited response, and extra info no longer contains the afore-mentioned line.

Comment: @Andrei please check now and in my project i did not get any error while compiling i am getting above error

Comment: We're not understanding each other. You've posted an error message that says `[ERROR] Errors in 'file:/C:/Vijay...`. I'm interested in the log lines that are *directly beneath* the said error message, while running in debug as they usually contain more details.
You've posted a stacktrace, but I don't know if it's the right one, because it doesn't say anything about any error message.
So can you show a chunk of the stacktrace that contains the error message and also offers more details?

Comment: Try running in strict mode (pass `-strict` or `-failOnError`)